# How to avoid page refresh on portfolio pagination in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using Unicon theme in wordpress which provides a post type "portfolio", I have used portfolio widget in a page, which displays a grid view of portfolio posts, but whenever I click on "load more" the whole page refreshes to show more portfolio posts, I don't want the page to get refreshed every time a person clicks load more. can someone please help me?

Here is the link of my website of portfolio grid view widget
https://anglehomes.co.uk/home-agency/#ptf

Here is the code for the post type "portfolio".

```php
function minti_pagination() {
    if( is_singular() )
        return;

    global $wp_query;

    /* Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;

    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

    /*  Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;

    /*  Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }

    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    echo '<div id="pagination" class="clearfix"><ul>' . "\n";

    /*  Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li class="pagination-prev">%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>') );

    /*  Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="current"' : '';

        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li><span>...</span></li>';
    }

    /*  Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="current"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }

    /*  Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li><span>...</span></li>' . "\n";

        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="current"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }

    /*  Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li class="pagination-next">%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>') );

    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: To do that you have to use Ajax pagination. In Wordpress there are lots of plugin for this. Just search for it. :)

Comment: @chefboyronron But its a custom post type provided by theme, I don't think the plugin can make it work?